# How do I do 3D contour plotting of a 3D dataset in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, data-visualization, volume

Let's say that I have wind speed values for values of latitude, longitude, and height (all plotted on rectangular coordinates) - each with a certain value of wind speed. I would then want to highlight the regions where, say, wind speed is greater than 200 m/s.

How would I do this?

And could I take this even further? If, say, maybe I wanted to draw an outline of regions with wind speed greater than 100 m/s?

Comment: You could have a look at the Matlab [3D visualization examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f5-6010.html) for inspiration.

Comment: @InquilineKea: I recommend the excellent *volume visualization* [video tutorial series](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2009/10/23/basics-volume-visualization-19-defining-scalar-and-vector-fields/) of 9 parts posted on Doug Hull's MathWorks blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isosurface is probably what you're looking for
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isosurface.html

(PS: for plotting wind-velocities you may want to look at quiver3
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quiver3.html)